# ¿Cómo crear y borrar una carpeta?

Tags: c

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño programa que cree una carpeta en el sistema Windows en un lugar específico desde C.

He creado programas en C pero no de este tipo, ¿me pueden orientar en este problema? **¿Cómo crear y borrar una carpeta?**

Comment: Podría revisar https://linux.die.net/man/2/mkdir para la creación de directorios.

Answer (score 6):

#### Como crear una carpeta en lenguaje C :

usando la función [mkdir()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html)

```
mkdir("c:/directorio", 0777);
```

`0777` es una mascara que define permisos rwx.

---

#### Como borrar una carpeta en lenguaje C

usando la función [rmdir()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/rmdir.html)

```
rmdir("c:/directorio");
```

Comment: La única respuesta completa que incluye cómo borrar y no sólo cómo crear la carpeta

Answer (score 4):

Tienes varias respuestas ya con [`mkdir`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mkdir.html) (que es lo correcto), así que voy a poner una respuesta **alternativa que funcionará pero que deberías evitar** usando [`system`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/system.html):

```
// crear carpeta
system("mkdir nombreCarpeta");

// borrar carpeta
system("rmdir nombreCarpeta");
```

Esos comandos crearán y borrarán una carpeta en tu sistema, pero no deberías usarlos, en su lugar opta por algo similar a lo que sugiere [Elenasys en su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/27228/250). Lo que sugiero es más un ejemplo de lo que no se debe hacer, y las razones para no usarlo:

- **Es potencialmente peligroso**: si controlas lo que pasas a `system` no debería haber problema, pero si usas entradas de usuario, te arriesgas a que puedan destruir tu sistema (literalmente: imagina que el usuario pone como nombre de carpeta `nombreCarpeta; format c:` o `nombreCarpeta; rm -rf ~`, y no lo saneas antes de pasárselo a `system`).
- **Es más lento y requiere más memoria**: `mkdir` ejecuta la rutina del sistema que crea un directorio, mientras que con `system(mkdir ...)` se crea un nuevo proceso y desde él se llama al programa `mkdir` (que no tiene por qué coincidir con la rutina `mkdir`).
- **Presenta mala portabilidad y no funcionará en todos los sistemas**: puede darse el caso de que algunos comandos estén deshabilitados en tu sistema, entonces no funcionarán. Además, hay comandos que son diferentes en los diferentes sistemas, y eso hará que tu programa sea específico para una plataforma (o que tengas que añadir más código).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <direct.h>
int main()
{
mkdir("c:/msssssssslder");
return 0;
}
```

ya encontré la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es una función, `mkdir("dirección");` hace el trabajo.

También puedes usar la función `CreateDirectory()` ubicada en windows.h.

Si lo que quieres es algo gráfico que te deje "hacer click" en los folders y te dé más opciones podrías considerar importar otros programas, ya que esto requiere más tiempo de desarrollo.